# Springboot endpoints without controller

Tags: spring-boot

I have a simple Springboot project with an entity as:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @NonNull
    @Size(min=3, max=100)
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    @NonNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty
    @NonNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    private boolean isAccountNonExpired = true;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    private boolean isAccountNonLocked = true;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    private boolean isCredentialsNonExpired = true;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    private boolean isEnabled = true;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    public void addRole(Role r) {
        roles.add(r);
    }

    public User() {}

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Role role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
```

I have created a controller for `/users` but not for `/roles`

However, under the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/users/2/roles`I get a pointer to

```
role: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/roles/1"
},
```

Where `/roles/1` produces

```
{
name: "ROLE_USER",
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/roles/1"
},
role: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/roles/1"
},
users: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/roles/1/users"
}
}
}
```

So it appears at least to an extent Springboot automatically generates some paths.

Can anybody please provide some context for this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using some dependency which generates that for you. I guess that it could be [spring-data-rest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest). If you don't want that, remove that dependency, use `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency and then only endpoints which you create would be available.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am! I also have spring-boot-starter-web, is there any issue in keeping both?

Comment: `spring-data-rest` creates automatically endpoints based on your entities. Maybe it's possible to somehow disable generation, but I have no experiences with it. Try to search [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: No it's quite convenient really, thanks for pointing that out! :)